# Linear operator composition and dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let V be linear space, dim(V) = 50. 
Whether there is such linear operator F on V that dim(Im(F)) = 49 and dim(Im(F∘F) = $47$ ? 
My teacher showed me this:

> $dim(im(F)) = 49 \quad  => \quad  dim(ker(F)) = 1 $
>   $dim(im(F∘F)) = 47 \quad  => \quad  dim(ker(F∘F)) = 3$ 
>  
>   Let $\hat v$ be base of $Ker(F) \quad => \quad$  $F(\hat v) = 0$ 
>   $F(F(\hat v)) = F(0) = 0 \quad  =>  \quad \hat v \ \epsilon \   Ker(F∘F) $ 
>   So let $\hat v, v_1, v_2$ be base of $F^2$ (by Stenitz exchange lemma). 
>   Therefore: 
>  
>   $F(F(\hat v)) = 0$ 
>   $F(F(v_1)) = 0  \quad  => \quad \exists w_1 \ \ F(v_1) = w_1$ 
>   $F(F(v_2)) = 0  \quad  => \quad \exists w_2 \ \ F(v_2) = w_2$ 
>   $w_1, \  w_2 \ne 0$ because in such case $F(v_1) = F(v_2) = 0\ $ so $\ v_1, > v_2 \ \epsilon \ ker(F) $ and $ v_1, v_ 2$ are lineary independent with $\hat v  \ =>  \ dim(ker(F)) > 1 \ => \ $  contradition
>   So  $F(w_1) = F(w_2) = 0 $

And here I'm lost. 
My teacher said that $w_1,w_2$ are lineary independent and that implies that $w_1, w_2 \ \epsilon \   ker(F) \ => \ dim(F) > 1 $ 
 I don't understand why $w_1, w_2$ are lineary independent and how can they be in $ker(F)$ when they belong to space with lower dimension than 50. 
I would really appreciate some explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $w_1$ and $w_2$ are not linearly independent, we can find $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ such that $\lambda_1w_1+\lambda_2w_2=0$.  But
$$
\lambda_1w_1+\lambda_2w_2=\lambda_1F(v_1)+\lambda_2F(v_2)=F(\lambda_1v_1+\lambda_2v_2),
$$
so that $\lambda_1v_1+\lambda_2v_2\in\ker F$.  But, we know that $\ker F$ is generated by $v$, so that $\lambda_1v_1+\lambda_2v_2=\lambda_v v$ for some $\lambda_v$.  This shows that $v_1,v_2,v$ is not a linearly independent set, which is a contradiction (as we assumed they are a basis for $\ker F\circ F$).

So, it must be the case that $w_1$ and $w_2$ are linearly independent.

As for your second question... I'm not sure I follow.  Though they come from a lower-dimensional space, they are still part of your original $V$; they are from a lower-dimensional *subspace* of $V$. Note that they are contained in $\ker F$ because, for instance,
$$
F(w_1)=F(F(v_1))=(F\circ F)(v_1)=0
$$
by assumption, because $v_1\in\ker F\circ F$.

Comment: So how you can determine coordinates of $w_1, w_2$ in 50 dimensions ? I mean I don't understand how can you compare vectors linear dependency when they have different number of coordinates -> for example (1,2,1) and (2,4)  - how can you say they are lineary dependent or not ? What if i would apply transformation D:V->V where ker(D) = 1 let's say a 40 times ? Would kernel of(D∘D...∘D) contain bunch of vectors with different number of coordinates ?

Comment: @MrPatience Regardless of the dimensions of the subspaces they might lie in, all of these vectors are elements of $V$, so they will have 50 coordinates each. Think about the analogous situation in $\mathbb R^2$: the $x$-axis is a one-dimensional subspace of the plane, but the vectors $(a,0)$ that lie on the $x$-axis still have two components.